# Resources for code generation of database objects

Tags: oracle, resources, code-generation, data-access

I am working a project where I need to generate a series of classes to represent/access data in the database. Third party projects such as hibernate or subsonic are not an option. I am new in this subject domain, so I am looking for information on the topic. The project is in .net and I am using MyGeneration. I am primarily looking for information.

**What is your single best resource for topics on code generation of data access?**

Please post only one link at a time and look for your resource before posting. If you find your resource, please vote up instead of posting it. . 
( I am not interesting in rep, just information)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using .NET? Try [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/)

Answer (score 1):

ORAPig generates Python interfaces for Oracle packages.  A Postgresql module is being worked on.

http://code.google.com/p/orapig